# How to add new line character in notepad++ like one would do in Vim?

Tags: notepad++, special-characters, newlines

I have a bash script which parse text files. In these text files some lines contains a new line character, when I open the file with Vim it looks like this:

```
data 1=part 1 ^M part 2
data 2=part 1
```

I inserted the `^M` character in vim thanks to <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The script will consider each line of the file as the description of a data and will understand that `data 1` is a text containing a new line.

Now my coworked need to create the same kind of file but he won't use Vim:

- If he uses <kbd>enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> that will create a new line and my script will not work properly (considering both part of `data1` as two separate data lines).
- If he insert `\n` or `\r` manually the script will considering that `data 1` is a single line of text containing the character `\` followed by `n` or `r` without special meaning.

How can he produce the same file with an editor like notepad++? I.e. how can he add a new line character which will not be interpreted by notepad++

Note that my question is about doing it with notepad++ because modifying the script would be an enormous inconvenient.

Comment: Which line break character/type is being used in the file to separate the records onto their own lines? CR, LF, both?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: The files are created on windows thus I'd say the standard CR + LF

Comment: So you're trying to insert/show the ASCII character "ALT+13" (just CR) instead of treating it as a CR/LF, correct?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 You're probably kind of right but `alt+13` insert a musical note ♪ on my setup

Comment: Sorry, it'd be `alt+013` in Windows. :)  Honestly I think you're out of luck, as NP++ seems to always treat CR as a new line, whether it includes an LF or not.. maybe a plugin to change that, but I can't find one off hand.  Maybe someone else knows. :)  Good luck!

Comment: Oh too bad... Thank you very much for your participation I really hope someone knows a way :-)

Answer (score 1):

`^M` is used for displaying the CARRIAGE RETURN (ASCII 13, 0x0D) character in vim.

You can type it with `Alt + 013` on the numpad in Notepad++. However, Notepad++ seems to always place a newly typed carriage return at the end of an existing line break, regardless what line break style is set for the file. So I would not recommend Notepad++ for this.

It is worth noting that mixed line breaks in a single file will always lead to problems when working with it. Some tools will even convert all line breaks to a certain format without the user's consent.